# Mysql/innodb deadlock on simple delete query

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

Mysql/innodb 8.0.16, read committed transactions, several statements in transaction raise deadlock on deletion of non intercepting rows. Trying to understand what is happening:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-05-14 21:57:44 0x7fe9546c6700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2852, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 14 row lock(s), undo log entries 25
MySQL thread id 146, OS thread handle 140640122267392, query id 1586 localhost 127.0.0.1 oc5z updating
DELETE FROM deal_product_rows_tmp WHERE batch_no=7533
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 11 page no 4 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db1`.`deal_product_rows_tmp` trx id 2852 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 14 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8000650e; asc   e ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000b25; asc      %;;
 2: len 7; hex 81000001340110; asc     4  ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80001d6e; asc    n;;
 4: len 4; hex 8010a626; asc    &;;
 5: len 4; hex 8000253a; asc   %:;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000986e; asc    n;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 8: len 30; hex 415254455820d184d0bed180d0bcd18b20d0bfd180d18fd0bcd0bed183d0; asc WRX                         ; (total 81 bytes);
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000208c40; asc        @;;
 10: len 1; hex 4d; asc M;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2853, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 12
MySQL thread id 147, OS thread handle 140640120497920, query id 1594 localhost 127.0.0.1 oc5z updating
DELETE FROM deal_product_rows_tmp WHERE batch_no=7534
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 11 page no 4 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `db1`.`deal_product_rows_tmp` trx id 2853 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 14 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8000650e; asc   e ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000b25; asc      %;;
 2: len 7; hex 81000001340110; asc     4  ;;
 3: len 4; hex 80001d6e; asc    n;;
 4: len 4; hex 8010a626; asc    &;;
 5: len 4; hex 8000253a; asc   %:;;
 6: len 4; hex 8000986e; asc    n;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 8: len 30; hex 415254455820d184d0bed180d0bcd18b20d0bfd180d18fd0bcd0bed183d0; asc WRX                         ; (total 81 bytes);
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000208c40; asc        @;;
 10: len 1; hex 4d; asc M;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 11 page no 4 n bits 96 index PRIMARY of table `db1`.`deal_product_rows_tmp` trx id 2853 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80006502; asc   e ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000b24; asc      $;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200000128012d; asc     ( -;;
 3: len 4; hex 80001d6d; asc    m;;
 4: len 4; hex 80109d40; asc    @;;
 5: len 4; hex 800023ba; asc   # ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800098e6; asc     ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;
 8: len 9; hex 466f696c20676c7565; asc Foil glue;;
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000005940; asc       Y@;;
 10: len 1; hex 4d; asc M;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `deal_product_rows_tmp` (
    `batch_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `bitrix_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `deal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `product_name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `tmp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tmp_id`),
    KEY `idx_deal_row_tmp_deal` (`deal_id`),
    KEY `idx_deal_row_tmp_batchno` (`batch_no`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

1) queries delete separated rows, how it is possible RECORD LOCKS on the same row?

2) even if the transactions applying lock on the same row, why deadlock? why first transaction can't wait until second release the lock ?

UPDATE1: App logic - spring boot app receiving rest call from crm system, fetching client order (deal) product rows and trying to sync the data in micro dwh. There are multiple statements in RC transaction, only one type of transaction implemented in this app. First statement REPLACE INTO deal table, this should prevent processing batches on the same deal_id in parallel (FK keys not used at the moment). Next the transaction inserting received product rows in "tmp" table and comparing on target "dwh" table. inserting missing deal products, updating status of "deleted" product rows. Next step deleting "tmp" data from deal_product_rows_tmp (point of deadlock) and final step - mark batch as completed (update batch set status=.. table where batch_no=? )

Comment: Let's see the entire transaction.  Or are you running `autocommit=ON` and these `DELETEs` stand alone?

Comment: Moral of the story:  Always check for errors, and be ready to rerun the transaction if you encounter a Deadlock.  There may come a time with gap locking (or something else) leads to an otherwise-inexplicable deadlock that can't really be prevented by changing the code.

Comment: @Rick the are multiple statements in transaction, I've updated post with app logic.

Answer (score 6):

Normally people are confused about [gap locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html) and the extra locking due to bad indexing on the whole table or more records than expected, but that is not your case:

- You have the appropriate secondary index
- The locks declare no gap locking is necessary (as expected)
- The records locked/wanted are different
- I cannot reproduce the issue unless I delete the `idx_deal_row_tmp_batchno` index
- The records are on the same page, but they should not, in theory, affect each other

From the limited information, what I can guess is:

- You are deleting several records in a batch (as one holds 3 row locks and the other 14)
- You run into a race condition, where Transaction 1 is able to lock `batch_no=7533` record, and Transaction 2 is able to lock `batch_no=7534`, but then they also want to update on separate queries (but the same transaction) the other records
- a dependency is detected and InnoDB kills the most recent one to prevent an infinite loop (deadlock)

They cannot just wait, because otherwise it would be an infinite wait (as they depend on each other). If it was not a cycle, the second transaction would indeed wait up to `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seconds.

There are several strategies you can do:

- Monitor deadlocks, if they are not common, just do nothing (retry on the application). As long as errors don't happen frequently they won't be a huge penalty
- Change your update strategy to prevent collisions (e.g. delete in a single, larger batch -although that may increase latency-, delete one row per transaction, make application coordinate for deletion, etc.
- Use the new 8.0 features `SKIP LOCKED` and `NOWAIT` to ignore immediately locked rows, specially intersting for batch processes: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/

Comment: Thanks for answer! My main goal is to understand the root of the issue, not to fix this particular case. I've already tried to change queries sequences, but got deadlocks in other places. I have expected row level locking in innodb on RC isolation level, but looks like I'm missing something totally. batch_no 7533 and 7534 dealing with different set of rows. They are related to different "deal_id", so I do not understand how can it possible to run into a race condition. Initially I've got the issue on google cloud sql based on mysql 5.6, now I'm testing vanila mysql 8. Same story every day

Comment: So, I've tried to change mysql version and hardware. An issue not in corrupted files. Maybe first question can I trust to SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output? The output says that I've got "RECORD LOCKS space id 11 page no 4" at both delete queries. Can I trust this information? How can I check which database object is assigned on "space id 11 page no 4" ?

Comment: > How can I check which database object is assigned on "space id 11 page no 4"

It says iy later, it is the 2 rows dumped on each query. As I say above, the rows are on the same page but the offset is different (they are locking different rows).

Comment: @jynus - Do the 'hex' lines provide any useful info?  Is there any clue in the Status whether this Delete was standalone versus part of a bigger transaction?

Comment: @Rick James Disclaimer I am not an expert on debugging deadlock debug as in my env, the code and traces I normally use make this redundant or simple (app debugging is king). hex just dumps the row contents, useful to identify the rows. 14 row lock(s) / 3 row lock(s) is what I use for my above guesses (concurrency with other previous deletes or other updates on other rows in the same transaction). Without app debugging, I would enable an audit log to capture the full transactions to confirm my suspicions (or look at the app code logic!).

Comment: @jynus I'm not sure that understand your last message. I see equal hex dump "RECORD LOCKS space id 11 page no 4 n bits 88". T1 " WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED" and T2 "HOLDS THE LOCK(S)"
I'm missing something ?
If I understand correctly your main message that issue not in the delete statement, but in next statement, where I'm trying to lock the same rows. I've described app logic in main post, next statement after deletion - update on batch table using PK batch_no. This also different rowset. I've doblecheked my code - T1 will try update batch_no=7533, T2 7534

Comment: @Triffids For what I can understand, the things you are modifying on one transaction in the tmp table may get deleted in the other transaction, creating a dependency loop. Either that, or you hit a MySQL bug.

Comment: @jynus "tmp table may get deleted in the other transaction" - this should never happen and if it is problem in my code I was expected to see the reason in SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS report. I will try collect more data, looks like after migration on mysql 8x I've got only 1 deadlock and 3 days ago. If the issue not disappear I will try to remove tmp table cleanup from code for tests. In previous tests on mysql 5.x tmp table cleanup removal just moved deadlock to another query/table. Hope this will give more information for analysis.

Comment: @jynus I've reproduced the issue on simple test case. Maybe you can comment simple and reproducible sample ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238756/mysql-innodb-trying-to-lock-uncommitted-row-from-parallel-transaction-deadlock

Comment: The answer you got there is right, you are suffering there gap-locking- you must index the table appropriately. Based on that I would say you probably are suffering from full table scan, which leads to that extra locking (e.g. maybe you have very few records). If I add the index and a few extra rows, no locking happens. Maybe you want to FORCE INDEX in this case.

Comment: Yes, normally in my "tmp" table should be 0 committed rows. Ok, maybe last question: do I understand correctly that full scan on innodb table apply record locks, even on uncommitted rows ?